# Retrieve value from other dataset during MySQL INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table with two integer columns.
One auto-increment index number and number.

What I want to do is INSERT a new row and use the number-value of the row with the highest index number.

I imagine of something like:

```
INSERT INTO `table`( `number`) VALUES (select `number` from `table` ORDER BY `index` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Why not `INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(SELECT MAX(indexNumberColumnName) FROM mytable)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query you posted would work. Here's another way to do it:

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`number`)
  SELECT MAX(`number`)
  FROM `table`
  WHERE `index` = (SELECT MAX(`index`) FROM `table`)
```

I'm not sure if it's faster, but you can verify that.

The `SELECT MAX(number)` prevents more than one value from being returned if, for example, the highest `index` value is 999 and more than one row has an `index` value of 999.